# install `lualatex` for use on the command line

Tags: luatex

I want to use `lualatex` as a separate process from the command line (or inside a program). I installed with

```
apt install texlive-luatex
```

but I still have the error `lualatex: command not found`

After I installed `texlive` and `texstudio` and then set the default compiler in `texstudio` options -> configure to `lualatex` and converted a tex.file I have now `texlualatex` available on the command line.

There is certainly a more straightforward way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lualatex` is a LaTeX based format, so in order to use it you have to install LaTeX, not just TeX. So you need at least the Ubuntu `texlive-latex-base` package.

But if you aren't an expert, it's usually better to just install `texlive-full` to avoid issues later on with missing packages.

Comment: thank you for your comment which does not answer the question. installing texlive-latex-base would not likely helped, installing texlive-luatex was sufficient, but required an additional process, which happend when I used texstudio the first time to compile with lualatex. THE QUESTION IS, WHAT IS THIS STEP? and HOW TO DO IT outside of texstudio.

Comment: @user855443 Not sure why this doesn't answer the question. If you look at the package details, you see that `lualatex` is not included in `texlive-luatex` but only in `texlive-latex-base`, so installing just `texlive-luatex` is certainly *not* sufficient. If you still get an error after installing `texlive-latex-base` then it at least shouldn't be `command not found`.

Comment: sorry. I see that `texlive-latex-base` is installed on my system and thus I got `lualatex` there. I have not intentionally installed it - I believe - and think perhaps `texstudio` which I installed has brought it in... You have answered the question, thank you and I beg you pardon for the inconsiderate answer. I have accepted your answer now.

Comment: @user855443 Yes, `texstudio` depends on a bunch of TeX Live packages, including `texlive-latex-base`.

Comment: that did trick me. now things work smoothly. thank you for the help.